# Joomla Question: How to have different image in Intro Text and Main Text

Tags: joomla

Joomla Question: Is there a way to have a different image in intro text? I plan to place a different and smaller image in the introtext.

Answer (score 1):

Could one not duplicate the the opening paragraph/content above the [Read More] line, except with whatever changes are needed? Then, in the article's Advanced Parameters, set the [Intro Text] value to "Hide" so the intro doesn't appear when the article is displayed normally?

Answer (score 1):

look here:
http://www.theartofjoomla.com/home/5-commentary/81-joomlas-hidden-feature-hiding-intro-text.html

Answer (score 0):

I added these code and it works well in my case

```
<?php
$text = $article->introtext;
if(preg_match('/<\s*img[^>]+>/Ui', $text, $matches)){
$image=$matches[0];
$text = str_replace($image,'',$text);
}
if ($matches) {
$image = str_replace('img src="','img width="100px" src="',$image);
$image = str_replace("caption","", $image);
echo '' . $image . '';
}
else {echo '<img width="100px" src="/images/defaultarticleimage.jpg"
 class="defaultArticleImage" />';}
 ?>
```

add to the file components/com-contents/view/category/tmpl/default_articles.php (copy this file to your template first)

Answer (score -1):

It's not possible with the current Joomla code.

The intro text is used to display a brief intro the article (usually on the main page) and then once the user opens the article, the intro text is displayed at the top before the rest of the text